# copying files from library to another library using SPFx

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

I am looking for some examples on how to copy files from one library to another library using SharePoint Framework (spfx).
Anyone has got some samples?
If you have examples that are not using PNP, those are great as well.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article about using SharePoint SPFx extension to copy and move for your reference:

https://www.m365-dev.com/2020/01/22/sharepoint-spfx-extension-advanced-copy-and-move/